# Segfault from execvp

Tags: c, unix, execvp

I'm trying to exec input that I get from a socket. I take the message buffer and put it into a `char *[]` and it is null terminated it works for `ls` but it won't work with paramaters like `ls -la`.

```
char *CMD[msg.c+1];
CMD[msg.c] = NULL;
```

Here is me parsing and using `execvp`.

```
//parse
char *tmp = NULL;
tmp = strtok(msg.v,space);
for(i = 0; i < msg.c; i++){
    CMD[i] = tmp;
    tmp = strtok(NULL,space);
    printf("%s\n",CMD[i]);
}

int fd[2];
pipe(fd);
pid_t pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) {
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 1);
        msg.c = execvp(CMD[0],CMD);
    }
```

Comment: Have you actually read the [`execvp` man page](http://man.cx/exec%282%29).  None of the arguments you provide match the types expected by `execvp()`.

Comment: I have Im unsure about the first arg like what to put I found that puting ls worked.. so thats what it is but then i thought it char*[] that does into the second

CMD = {"ls","-la",NULL}

Comment: Your usage or `strtok` is not safe. If you want to save the strings returned you should duplicate them, e.g. with `strdup`. You also doesn't check for it to return `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably so late answer that no one cares... To summarise there are some issues in your program, but I do not really know why you got segmentation fault or if you already fixed that.

In the code:

- use of `strsep(3)` instead of [obsolete](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=strtok&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=OpenBSD%20Current&arch=i386&format=html%20obsolete) `strtok(3)`
- `strdup(3)` to be sure no other code modifies `msg`, if not, then you can remove strdup and free
- added some error handling with `err(3)` to find errors early (earlier).
- you cannot do `msg.c = execvp(CMD[0], CMD)`, the program is executing CMD and will never return; to be able to retrieve the exit code, use `wait(2)` or `waitpid(2)`
- variable length of arrays (`char *CMD[msg.c+1]`) is allowed in C99, but I do not use it, you can if you want. :)

And here is the lengthy code, probably a lot of bugs, but please tell me and I will try to fix:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_ARGS 10

int 
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
        char *cmd[MAX_ARGS];
        char *s;
        char buf[256];
        char msg[] = "ls -la /";
        int n;
        int fd[2];
        pid_t pid;
        int stat;

        if ((s = strdup(msg)) == NULL)
                err(1, "strdup");
        for (n = 0; n < MAX_ARGS && (cmd[n] = strsep(&s, " ")) != NULL; n++)
                ;

        if (pipe(fd) == -1)
                err(1, "pipe");
        switch ((pid = fork())) {
        case -1:
                close(fd[0]);
                close(fd[1]);
                err(1, "fork");
        case 0: /* child */
                close(fd[0]);
                dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fd[1]);
                execvp(cmd[0], cmd);
                err(1, "execvp");
        default: /* parent */
                free(s);
                close(fd[1]);
                while ((n = read(fd[0], buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0)
                        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, n);
                waitpid(pid, &stat, 0);
                fprintf(stderr, "child(%d) exited with %d\n",
                        pid, WEXITSTATUS(stat));
        }
        return (0);
}
```